# Multiply a Sum by a factor

Tags: summation, series-expansion

A very simple question: How can I tell to Mathematica that:
$\begin{equation} x*\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\,b_kx^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\,b_kx^{k+1}\end{equation}
$

I tried to multiply but Mathematica gives me only
$\begin{equation} x*\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\,b_kx^k\end{equation}.
$
I am trying to apply Frobenius method, and I need to collect the same powers of $x$ in my final equation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ReplaceAll`:

```
sum = Sum[Subscript[b, k] x^k, {k, 0, Infinity}];
x sum  /. a_. Sum[s_, r__] :> Sum[a s, r]
TeXForm @ %
```

> $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } b_k x^{k+1}$